# upgraded galaxy S5 to 4.4.4 and now it wont show up in ADB

Tags: android

I just installed the 4.4.4 update to my galaxy s5 and now I cant get my phone to connect to ADB.

I have the latest SDK and I have the latest usb drivers installed on my computer

when I tried to update the driver on my phone through device manager I get an error

"The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to worth with windows for x64-based systems"

but im pointing it to the latest usb driver from google, so I dont understand how it couldnt be compatible with my device.

please help!!!

edit: just to be clear, it was working fine before the update, it is only after that it has stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the **Samsung Universal USB drivers for mobile devices** and install it on your Windows 64-bit operating system.

You can get the USB drivers directly from [Bittorrent](https://thepiratebay.se/torrent/11032493/Samsung_USB_Drivers_for_Mobile_Devices_v1.5.45_Installer), or go to http://www.samsung.com/ and search for the USB drivers there.

Once USB drivers installation is finished:

1. Enable `USB Debugging` option in your S5 device.
2. Connect your S5 via the USB cable to Windows.
3. Open a command prompt, type: `adb kill-server`, then `adb start-server`, then `adb devices`. The last command will tell you whether your S5 can be connected successfully to your Windows PC. Note: `adb` is located at **../android-sdk/platform-tools/** directory.
4. Start your Android project via your IDE (Eclipse, Android Studio,
   etc).

Comment: ugh, i'm a moron, the update turned off USB debugging, so all I had to do was turn it back on. *embarrassed*

Comment: @DanielH: Don't feel bad. We all make mistakes from time to time. ;)